# Add n number of spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm generating a text report with the following format:

**Column1,Column2,Column3**

**Learn JavaScript,Learn Python,Learn Android**

As you can see the alignment is incorrect. What i want is to align it properly based on fixed length so that the corresponding values come under respective columns.

I'm new to JS and have limited time to explore.

My logic is to take 25 as the maximum length, as I'm sure it wouldn't exceed 25 and then calculate actual length of each column value and append the remaining number of spaces to it after subtracting the length of the column value from 25.

> **Update**

I solved this by using the following approach:

```
function align(data){
            if(data !== null && data !== undefined && data.length > 0){
                length = data.length;
                var value = "";
                if(staticLength > length){
                    for(var i=0;i<(staticLength-length);i++){
                        value += " ";
                    }
                }
                return data+value;
            }else{
                var value = "";
                for(var i=0;i<staticLength;i++){
                    value += " ";
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "limited time to explore" = "it's not that important"

Comment: you should try generating an `HTML` report rather than text as your requirement suggests. and if it's just a `CSV` report then you don't need to care about column size, just change the file extension to `.csv` and open with excel.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `padEnd()` method. Something like this:

```
str.padEnd(25);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd).